# XPath & XML modification

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML collection like this:

```
<test>
   <test1></test1>
   <test2></test2>
   <test3>
      <bla1></bla1>
      <bla2></bla2>
   </test3>
   <test3></test3>
</test>
```

I want to get all the nodes except for the test3 nodes. I have tried `/*[not(name()='test3')]`, but it does not work.

Also, is it possible with XPath to add a node to an XML collection? How can I do this?

Say I have XML like this:

```
<rootnode>
  <node1></node1>
</rootnode>
```

and I want to add another node. How can I do this with XPath, or is this impossible?

I want to get all the nodes except for the test3 nodes (and its innernodes). so if there is a `<bla>` in test2, I want to get it.

Finally, say that I want to filter the test3 nodes by index. So I want to remove all test3 nodes except for the first one (or the second or third, defined by the index I give).

How would one do this?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer: it provides the *exact* XPath expression that selects the nodes you asked for. The currently selected answer is not correct, because it selects only element nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: You were only searching the root, but not the descendant nodes. Also, the `name()` check should be avoided because it is unreliable when prefixes and namespaces are being used. Try this:

```
//*[not(ancestor-or-self::test3)]
```

2: XPath is querying XML only. However, there ar related technologies such as XSLT and XQuery which allow the transformation of XML. Or you can use a DOM in a programming language where you use XPath to identify the nodes and then operations on the DOM to modify them.

Comment: The problem with //*[not(self::test3)] is that it also returns the <bla></bla> nodes located in test3. I want to get rid of those 2.. Thx for the quick reply :)

Comment: You did write "all nodes except `test3`"... ;-) Do you want to get the inner nodes (e.g. if there was a `bla` node in `test2`, do you want it or not)?

Comment: Yes, I want to get all the nodes except for the test3 nodes (and its innernodes). so if there is a <bla> in test2, I want to get it.

Comment: Maybe I am not making myself clear :p The output I want to get is <test><test1></test1><test2></test2></test>. So it removes all the test3 nodes including its subnodes. Now say that <node2> also contains <bla> nodes, it has to keep that. If I use //not*[(self::test3)] it doesnt remove the subnodes in test3.. Hope you guys understand me :p

Comment: @Rise_against, loud and clear. Have you tried my edit from 10 minutes ago?

Comment: @Lucero, @Alejandro: I think that *my* answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

> Now what I want to accomplish is the
>   following, I want to get all the nodes
>   except for the test3 nodes.

**Use**:

```
    //node()[not(ancestor-or-self::test3) 
           and 
            not(self::processing-instruction('test3'))] 
   | 
    //*[not(ancestor-or-self::test3)]/@*[not(name()='test3')] 
   | 
    //*[not(ancestor-or-self::test3)]/namespace::*[not(name()='test3')]
```

**Do note** that in XPath every *element* is a *node*, but not every *node* is an *element*. The expression above selects every *node* in the document, whose name isn't `test3` and that has no parent or ancestor named `test3`.

**There are the following types of nodes** in the XPath data model:

1. `document-node()`  (also called "root node) -- selected by `/` .
2. `element()` node, selected by a name test in the `child` axis, such as `child::test3` just `test3` or `child::*` or just `*` .
3. `text()` node, selected by `text()` .
4. `comment()` node, selected by `comment()`
5. `processing-instruction()` node, selected by `processing-instruction()` or by `processing-instruction('someName')` .
6. `attribute()` node, selected by a name test on the `attribute` axis, such as `attribute::x` or `@x` or `@*`.
7. Namespace node, selected by a name test or a wild card on the `namespace` axis, such as `namespace::x` or `namespace::*`.

**Do note**: The node- test `node()` selects any of the above 7 types of nodes (which are allowed on the currently specified or default axis. Without axis specified, `node()` selects any node of type 1 - 5 above.

Comment: I think OP has meant element instead of node. Besides that, this is a good answer, also +1